# video masking in html

Tags: html, video, svg

How we mask the video in html with available SVG?

I tried with following code but it will not dispalying in chrome?

```
<video id="video_target" src="oceans-clip.ogg" type="video/ogg" autoplay></video>
<svg>
   <mask id="video_mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <text x="300" y="190">VIDEO</text>
   </mask>
</svg>
```

Can anyone please answer how to display a SVG masked video in chrome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG video mask in html not showing in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219813/svg-video-mask-in-html-not-showing-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but HTML5 video masking is currently supported by webkit browsers only.
You could make a workaround with some javascript for instance this chroma-key effect as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Manipulating_video_using_canvas

But for HTmL5 canvas, you're out of luck!